Spin states of meson
I am currently reading the book "Effective Field Theories" of Petrov and Blechman. In chapter 5.3 the book derives the heavy meson states, with the given basis,
$b_a( \uparrow) =\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$, $b_a( \uparrow) =\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$
for the heavy quark spin part and with the  light antiquarks
$\overline{q}_b (\downarrow) =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -1 \\
    0
\end{pmatrix}$, $\overline{q}_b (\uparrow) =
\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    -1
\end{pmatrix}$.
Afterwards the book derives the meson spin states.
For the pseudoscalar state we have
$B_{ab} \, \propto b_a( \uparrow) \overline{q}_b (\downarrow)+ b_a( \downarrow) \overline{q}_b (\uparrow)$.
My question is, why is there a plus sign between this linear combination and not a minus sign.
In the normal SU(2) couplin of two spin 1/2 states we obtain one triplett and one singlett state. The singlett state is
$ |0,0\rangle \propto |\uparrow \rangle |\downarrow\rangle - |\downarrow\rangle |\uparrow\rangle$. Here is a minus sign and I understand why, but why is there a plus sign for the meson state. I suppose that this has something to do with the negative sign of the antiquark spin components.

Is the book assuming some  $SU(N)$ flavour symmetry on the quarks?

Yes there is given a SU(3) symmetry of the light quark flavors. But I don' t think that this has something to so with constructing the spin states.

I would double check the definitions given, but I am sure the answer is in that 'spin down' states of anti-matter are implicitly defined with a minus sign in them. I.e. $\hat{C}\left( |\uparrow\rangle \otimes \psi\right) = -|\downarrow \rangle \otimes \psi^c$
